# Time conversion in java of format 20170526T043000Z

Tags: java, datetime, time, calendar, jodatime

I have a time string in the following format 20170526T043000Z how can I convert it to milliseconds.

Comment: Use `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the value to a `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` from there you can get the millisecond values. Have a look at [Parsing and Formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat in java since you know the date format.

Eg:

```
String testDate = "20170526T043000Z";

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd'T'HHmmss");
Date parsedDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(testDate);
System.out.println("Time in millis " + parsedDate.getTime());
```